# QTextEdit без полосы прокрутки

Tags: qt

Есть `QTextEdit` с фиксированной шириной но не фиксированной высотой. В `QTextEdit` вводится текст, после которого `QTextEdit` может иметь полосу прокрутки и может не иметь полосу прокрутки. Как при нажатии на некоторою `QPushButton` изменить висоту(на минимальное значение) так чтобы `QTextEdit` не имел полоси прокрутки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QPushButton>

class MainWindow : public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT
    QTextEdit *_textEdit;
    QPushButton *_button;
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0):
        QWidget(parent),
        _textEdit(new QTextEdit),
        _button(new QPushButton("Resize"))
    {
        _textEdit->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
        connect(_button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(resizeTextEdit()));
        setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
        layout()->addWidget(_button);
        layout()->addWidget(_textEdit);
    }
public slots:
    void resizeTextEdit(){
        int height = _textEdit->document()->size().height();
        _textEdit->setFixedHeight(height);
        updateGeometry();
    }
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Answer (score 1):

Добрый вечер, попробуйте

```
textEdit->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
textEdit->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

([Источник](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/8974-QTextEdit))

Comment: не меняется высота

Answer (score 0):

А если использовать 
void    setSizePolicy ( QSizePolicy::Policy horizontal, QSizePolicy::Policy vertical )

сначала устанавливать

```
setMinimumSize(200, 200);
setMaximumSize(200, 200);
setSizePolicy ( QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed )
```

А при нажатии кнопки вызывать

```
setMinimumSize(200, 200);
setMaximumSize(200, 999999);
setSizePolicy ( QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Minimum)
```

Пишу по памяти, мог ошибиться. Направление мысли думаю понятно

Все элементы окна должны быть помещены в какой нибудь layout.

Дело в том, что точная реализация зависть от некоторых факторов :
 -Достаточного ли размера окно для растягивания QTextEdit или необходимо окно растягивать тоже;
 -какие элементы ещё есть на окне и какое должно быть их поведение при растягивании QTextEdit'a
В общем нужно смотреть формочку

Comment: не меняется высота

Comment: Достаточно размера окно для растягивания QTextEdit. На окне есть только QTextEdit и QPushButton. Все элементы окна помещены в layout, все равно не работает.